# Counting li items from a html file using php

Tags: php, html, web-crawler

I have an HTML file that contains many many JUST "li" tags no head and body tag and any thing else. I want to count them using PHP. how can I do this?

However, I tried this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
DOMDocument::loadHTML($tmp_file);
$count = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
echo count($count);
```

but it returns 1.

Here is the $tmp_file (I don't know how many is them will be retrieved (may be hundred of them) but I just add 5 of them to here):

```
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426832/میروسلاو-ژیوکو-سرمربی-تیم-والیبال-سایپا-شد" target="_blank" title="میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد">میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426824/فدرر-از-نظر-فیزیکی-شرایط-سال-قبل-را-ندارم" target="_blank" title="فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم">فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426817/شکست-تیم-&#171;الف&#187;-والیبال-ساحلی-ایران-مقابل-هلند" target="_blank" title="شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند">شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند</a>
</li>
<li class="news-video">
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426815/5-حرکت-دیدنی-در-لیگ-تابستان-NBA؛-96-04-21" target="_blank" title="5 حرکت دیدنی در لیگ تابستان NBA؛ 96/04/21">5 حرکت دیدنی در لیگ تابستان NBA؛ 96/04/21</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426813/معرفی-هیات-مدیره-جدید-صندوق-حمایت-از-پیشکسوتان" target="_blank" title="معرفی هیات مدیره جدید صندوق حمایت از پیشکسوتان">معرفی هیات مدیره جدید صندوق حمایت از پیشکسوتان</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426808/رحیمی،-یزدانی-و-قاسمی-در-رده-اول-تا-سوم-جهان" target="_blank" title="رحیمی، یزدانی و قاسمی در رده اول تا سوم جهان">رحیمی، یزدانی و قاسمی در رده اول تا سوم جهان</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426792/جوکوویچ-منتظر-رویارویی-با-بردیچ-هستم" target="_blank" title="جوکوویچ: منتظر رویارویی با بردیچ هستم">جوکوویچ: منتظر رویارویی با بردیچ هستم</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you paste in some of the html it's looking at?

Comment: and many other just like this li tag...

Comment: Please update your question with any additional info/code instead of in a comment.

Comment: It's returning "1" because it's coming back as true.

Comment: Please check your error log (or better yet, turn on display errors, here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings) and check if you get a bunch of warnings when trying to parse the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of that issue was that I just want to achieve that a tags and grab their link, and I just want to use parsing, but some times you should use your Intel i9 in your mind and think better, so instead of getting `<li>` tags I directly targeted `<a>` tags, and it works:

Here is the code:

```
$this->dom = new DOMDocument();
@$this->dom->loadHTMLfile($tmp_file);
$this->as = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($this->as as $a) { ...
```

and as each of this items were saved to the database, then I can't get count of them from the database with MySQL queries, that's it!

Answer (score 8):

You're close. I think what you're looking for is the following :

```php
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html); // or @$dom->loadHTMLFile($filename); if providing filename rather than actual HTML content

$count = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length;
echo $count;
```

Depending on your value of `$tmp_file` you would use either [`loadHTML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) if it contains the actual content, or [`loadHTMLFile()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) if it contains the filename. (Note that these methods should not be called statically.)

The method [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object with a `length` property containing the number of found nodes.

You can try the code [here](https://repl.it/Kx9n).

This **DOM parsing** approach is preferable to string or regular expression searches since it is designed to account for the many variable ways that HTML may be acceptably written (ie. inconsistent spacing, attribute order).

Comment: as said above , length in not works it should be length() , by the way , thanx man, i'll post my answer her as soon as possible

Comment: It should indeed be `->length` and not `->length()` since `length` is a _property_ of `DOMNodeList`, not a _method_, and properties are accessed without the parentheses. If you're still not getting the desired output, than the issue is elsewhere, possibly the use of `loadHTML()` instead of `loadHTMLFile()`?

Answer (score 5):

You can do a very simple `Substring Count` for `<li>` (or -li-) on that string and it would return the number of items.
See here: <kbd>[**function.substr-count**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)</kbd>

```
$count = substr_count($html,'<li>'); //where $html holds your piece of HTML.
```

Comment: still returning 0

Comment: In the example the OP posted in a comment, it's actually `<li >` (with an extra space).

Comment: still zero buddy (with extra space)!

Comment: @Er.Ellison `substr_count($html,'<li >');` works perfectly for me when I try with the HTML in your question. Of course, you need to change `$html` to the variable that actually holds your HTML data. Try it: https://3v4l.org/daX97

Comment: If you are going to go this route, I would recommend checking for `</li>` or `<li` so you can avoid worrying about extra space/attributes in the tag.

Answer (score 4):

You were close.

Try this:

```
$count = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li")->length;
```

And change this `echo count($count);` to `echo $count`

Comment: it does not recognises the length

Comment: Sorry, it was `->length`.

Comment: this is getting funny ,

Comment: it return 0 this time :)))))

Comment: @Er.Ellison Please check my comment for your question.

Comment: It is returning 0 because you are trying to count non-array variable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, loadHTML loads from an HTML inside a string. If $tmp_file is the name of the file, you should use loadHTMLFile.

Also, loadHTML is not static, so you need to do `$dom->loadHTML($tmp_file);`

Now the answer to the question.

What `getElementsByTagName()` returns is a DOMNodeList. As an object, probably the `count()` function will just say 1, but DOMNodeList has a property called `length`. If you query only `li` elements and then read the `length` it will give the quantity of `li` elements.

As a test:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML("<li>test 1</li><li>test 2</li><li>test 3</li><li>test 4</li>");
$count = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
echo $count->length; //Prints 4
```

Inside the `<ul>` I've set up four `<li>` elements.

Comment: the $tmp_file is retrieving data from a link and puts it to a tmp file using file_put_contents , so , so far i have a html file that contains JUST "li"tags in it (even whenever i tried to load the tmp file in browser , it just shows some crazy characters to me) , it does NOT have any body or html tag

Comment: @Er.Ellison it doesn't matter, it's just an example. You can put only `<li>` tags and it works. I'll change my example to reflect your case.

Comment: believe me i'm trying as u said but it return 0 , here is the reurning result :

Comment: u see the zero in first that the result of echo $count->length;

Comment: Can you post what `echo $tmp_file;` shows? Just to discard things. Also, are you using `$dom->loadHTML() `?

Comment: @Er.Ellison Check what `$dom->loadHTML($tmp_file);` returns. If it fails because can not parse it, it should return `false`. If that happens and you can't modify your input to fix the html syntax errors, we should find another way to solve this problem. Maybe with regular expression. I'll try and see.

Comment: @Er.Ellison I did a test here - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f83d4e5fd24e73c66956b6fcc4dfe0f9b0fa6a1
There are some warnings, but it show 7 `<li>`elements at the end. It should work with the data you posted.

Comment: yea man . thanx alot , i also reached to that solution : check out this

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/169ee1582f63b5a7ece6185ccc24591b6c0888ff

Comment: it now return 250 , I told u that idont know how many of them will been retrieved by crawler now that is 250 !!!!! amazing

Comment: @Er.Ellison in the code that you have commented that it works for you, using `echo $as->length;` didn't work for you?
In any case, it's nice you found a solution! If none of the answer has solved your problem, you can now post your own answer and mark as accepted. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Could you try something like this? `$url` being the path to your html file?

```
$data = file($url);
$count = null;
foreach($data as $line){
    if (strpos($line,'<li')){
        ++$count;
    }
}

echo($count);
exit();
```

Comment: No bro, I think there is a typo in your answer, at '<li>', thank you for responding to my question, I have solved this problem with a another genius way, sorry about that I forgot to post my answer here, I'm currently working on a very serious project and I just came over to stack overflow when I can, by the way first of all thanks to Blaise (my man), second of all, I'll post my answer here as soon as I can! Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Haha! Glad you found an answer. I intentionally left off the closing of the opening <li> tag due to the space in the code!

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure all the lines are the same you do not even need to check for the `<li>` tag. Just do a quick count of the number of lines in the file and divide by 3:

```
$total_lines = count(file($html_file));
$num_list_items = $total_lines / 3;
```

$html_file should just be the path to the file. You do not need to parse the HTML so no need to create a new DOMDocument. This is much more efficient, but only if you know for sure that the entire file is formatted in this way.

Answer (score 3):

You just use the following code for get the `li` count from html page data

```
 $html_page_data='<li >
            <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426832/میروسلاو-ژیوکو-سرمربی-تیم-والیبال-سایپا-شد" target="_blank" title="میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد">میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد</a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426824/فدرر-از-نظر-فیزیکی-شرایط-سال-قبل-را-ندارم" target="_blank" title="فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم">فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم</a>
        </li>
        <li >
            <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426817/شکست-تیم-&#171;الف&#187;-والیبال-ساحلی-ایران-مقابل-هلند" target="_blank" title="شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند">شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند</a>
        </li>';
          $doc = new DOMDocument();
          $doc->loadHTML($html_page_data);
          libxml_clear_errors();
          $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
          $query = '//li'; //query pattern for find li
          $li_data= $xpath->query($query);
    echo  $li_data->length ; //output 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also use :

```
echo preg_match_all("~<li([^>]*)>~",file_get_contents("your_html_file")).PHP_EOL;
```

Test Results :

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat file
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426832/میروسلاو-ژیوکو-سرمربی-تیم-والیبال-سایپا-شد" target="_blank" title="میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد">میروسلاو ژیوکو سرمربی تیم والیبال سایپا شد</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426824/فدرر-از-نظر-فیزیکی-شرایط-سال-قبل-را-ندارم" target="_blank" title="فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم">فدرر: از نظر فیزیکی شرایط سال قبل را ندارم</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426817/شکست-تیم-&#171;الف&#187;-والیبال-ساحلی-ایران-مقابل-هلند" target="_blank" title="شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند">شکست تیم &#171;الف&#187; والیبال ساحلی ایران مقابل هلند</a>
</li>
<li class="news-video">
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426815/5-حرکت-دیدنی-در-لیگ-تابستان-NBA؛-96-04-21" target="_blank" title="5 حرکت دیدنی در لیگ تابستان NBA؛ 96/04/21">5 حرکت دیدنی در لیگ تابستان NBA؛ 96/04/21</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426813/معرفی-هیات-مدیره-جدید-صندوق-حمایت-از-پیشکسوتان" target="_blank" title="معرفی هیات مدیره جدید صندوق حمایت از پیشکسوتان">معرفی هیات مدیره جدید صندوق حمایت از پیشکسوتان</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426808/رحیمی،-یزدانی-و-قاسمی-در-رده-اول-تا-سوم-جهان" target="_blank" title="رحیمی، یزدانی و قاسمی در رده اول تا سوم جهان">رحیمی، یزدانی و قاسمی در رده اول تا سوم جهان</a>
</li>
<li >
    <a target="_blank" class="small-news-link" href="http://www.varzesh3.com/news/1426792/جوکوویچ-منتظر-رویارویی-با-بردیچ-هستم" target="_blank" title="جوکوویچ: منتظر رویارویی با بردیچ هستم">جوکوویچ: منتظر رویارویی با بردیچ هستم</a>
</li>


akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php -r 'echo preg_match_all("~<li([^>]*)>~",file_get_contents("file")).PHP_EOL;'
7
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (putting your example HTML in a file called "index.html"):

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("index.html");
$count = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
printf("Count: %d\n", count($count));
```

Edit: Although, as has been said, you can skip the `count()`:

```
$li_elems = $dom->getElementsByTagName("li");
printf("Count: %d\n", $li_elems->length);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parse:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
echo count($html->find('li'));
```

Comment: if its right for, please check it as correct answer )))

Answer (score 2):

I can hel you.

You should use this code:

```html
$numberOfListItems= $domElement->getElementsByTagName("li")->length;
```

$numberOfListItems contains needed value